# How to store the output files in the same folder as the original workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the VBA as below. It only works in the VBA module whenever I insert a module in any new Excel workbook. I wish to store it in Personal.xlsb and run it whenever I need it.

Can you please advise how can I modify it so that the output files (for example: Data 1, Data 2, Data 3... Data 99999) are stored in the same folder as the original workbook?

```
Sub SplitFixedRows()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile       

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  RowsInFile = InputBox("Please enter data size +1 header (Example: 11, 101, 501): ")

  Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1

  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))
  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data" & WorkbookCounter
    wb.Close

    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the original workbook.  In the following code I set `wbOrig` to the `ActiveWorkbook` when the code starts (and then use that object instead of `ThisWorkbook`).

```
Sub SplitFixedRows()
  Dim wbOrig As Workbook
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile       

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  RowsInFile = InputBox("Please enter data size +1 header (Example: 11, 101, 501): ")

  Set wbOrig = ActiveWorkbook    
  Set ThisSheet = wbOrig.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1

  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))
  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    wb.SaveAs wbOrig.Path & "\Data" & WorkbookCounter
    wb.Close

    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```